# Create a php variable from URL without question mark

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, query-string

I need to create a variable in PHP from a URL, which does not have a fully formed query string.

e.g. http://search.domain.com/domain2.com

In this example, the variable needs to be

```
$website='domain2.com'
```

Is there a way to convert the entered URL in address bar to my ?website=     variable?

An example would be the whois.domaintools service, which allows you to query a whois record from their website using the following url format:

http://whois.domaintools.com/domain.com

This then displays info based on the url you specified.

Can i achieve this using a MOD_Rewrite in the .htaccess, or can i use some PHP function like http_build_query to achieve this? I'm going around in circles and surely missing something obvious!

Comment: get the url string with `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` then you can do whatever string operations you need

Comment: You can use ``parse_url`` in PHP, e.g. ``parse_url('http://search.domain.com/domain2.com', PHP_URL_PATH);`` will return ``/domain2.com``.

Comment: So you would like to create a string like ``website.com?website=domain2.com`` from an input of ``http://search.domain.com/domain2.com`` ?

Comment: @alistaircol - yes - the last domain is user entered though, so will be dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to get your array $urlpart

```
$link = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; 

$urlpart = explode('/',trim(parse_url($link, PHP_URL_PATH), '/'));
```